# Type Mismatched on Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on Android app which uses Zxing to Scan QR Code on fragment, For achieving that I followed this Tutorial to get the Desired result.[Link I Followed to Scan QR on Fragment](https://tutorialwing.com/implement-android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxing-library-in-kotlin/)

The Code I used to Scan QR On **QRCodeFragment ** Fragment looks

```
class QRCodeFragment : Fragment() {

internal var txtName: TextView? = null
internal var txtSiteName: TextView? = null
internal var btnScan: Button? = null
internal var qrScanIntegrator: IntentIntegrator? = null


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qr_code, container, false)
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    txtName = view.findViewById(R.id.name)
    txtSiteName = view.findViewById(R.id.site_name)

    btnScan = view.findViewById(R.id.btnScan)
    btnScan!!.setOnClickListener { performAction() }

    qrScanIntegrator = IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this)
    qrScanIntegrator?.setOrientationLocked(false)

    // Different Customization option...
    qrScanIntegrator?.setPrompt(getString(R.string.scan_a_code))
    qrScanIntegrator?.setCameraId(0)  // Use a specific camera of the device
    qrScanIntegrator?.setBeepEnabled(false)
    qrScanIntegrator?.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true)

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}

private fun performAction() {
    qrScanIntegrator?.initiateScan()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (result != null) {
        // If QRCode has no data.
        if (result.contents == null) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.result_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            // If QRCode contains data.
            try {
                // Converting the data to json format
                val obj = JSONObject(result.contents)
                // Show values in UI.
                txtName?.text = obj.getString("name")
                txtSiteName?.text = obj.getString("site_name")

            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()

                // Data not in the expected format. So, whole object as toast message.
                Toast.makeText(activity, result.contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

}

From Main Activity I am Calling the the Fragment is like

```
    private fun ShowQRCodeFragment() {
    val newFragment = QRCodeFragment()
    val transaction1: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction1.replace(R.id.frameLayout, newFragment);
    transaction1.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction1.commit();
}
```

In the Main Fragment It shows me Type mismatched, I pointed on it it goes to Fragment name that is Extending **Fragment()**

```
 public Fragment() {
    initLifecycle();
}
```

Error Image Looks
[image]

if I change this It shows the Error on the Activity, From Where I am calling the Scan QR Fragment
[image: Error After Changing Fragment]

Comment: Try to find out the full name (including packages) of provided and requested class. One may be from AndroidX or support library, other from main API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `QRCodeFragment` class is extending `Fragment`, which? (check `import`s on top of a file)

we have [android.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) and [androidx.fragment.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment) - pick proper needed by your method

built-in `android.app.Fragment` is currently deprecated, you should use `androidx` version, but there is a chance that some libraries still needs original one (sadly)

Comment: I have Changed Fragment() to Another Type androidx fragment but the Issue Reamins the Same

Comment: import android.app.Fragment , this is Import

Comment: It will remain the same. Its is because of the super call.

Comment: inspect which `Fragment` is needed by your methods, e.g. `forFragment`. keep ctrl/cmd button and click it, tab with class will open, then inside keep ctrl/cmd pressed and move cursor on `Fragment` class which is parameter of your method - you will see full package of needed `Fragment`. besides that like other suggests: `super.onViewCreated` should be the first call in your overriden method, but still I don't think this is causing your issue...

Comment: It is Using    public Fragment() {
    }

Comment: this is not full class name, this is constructor

Comment: This is a simple thing. The **super.onViewCreated** needs to be called first..

Comment: maybe other method: try to replace `QRCodeFragment : Fragment` to `QRCodeFragment : android.app.Fragment` or `QRCodeFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` - after every change make clean build (Android Studio -> Build ->Rebuild project)

Comment: @Dev Bhattacharjee - could you please explain why this change should fix issue? it is saying type mismatch and moving some line won't change type for sure...

Comment: Since **QRCodeFragment** is extending **Fragment class** and the **Fragment implementation** requires the base class functions to be called.. **this** in his case is referring to the base class Fragment not QRCodeFragment. To solve this, he needs to call super.onViewCreated first.

Comment: But as I Changed the Fragment to android.app.Fragment the same Error Goes on Where I am Calling the Fragment From main activity

Comment: It will continue to show **Fragment** instead of **QRCodeFragment** everywhere as your **this** is referring to **Fragment class**. All these happening because of not calling **super.onViewCreated** first.

Comment: in there you are using `SupportFragmentManager` which accepts `androidx` `Fragment` only (`androidx` is "support library" actually)... this is architectural problem, Zxing is using built-in `Fragment`s sadly, so if you really need to use this lib in this version you have to make some switching between `supportFragmentManager` and built-in (not-support)

Comment: Please dont mind I did'nt Understand the Point super.onViewCreated first, Actually I am Extending the Fragment and have two methods, onCreateview and viewcreated

Comment: you have `onViewCreated` method overriden and in last line you are calling `super.onViewCreated` - this should (must?) be the first line, not last

Comment: What I need to Do that Zxing Library change to other or my Library goes to ZXing

Comment: another option for solution: use `Integrator.forSupportFragment(this)` and use `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` in import

Comment: You should look for **Inheritance** and calling **super class functions**. Your **QRCodeFragment extends the android Fragment class**. **onViewCreated in child class requires calling the super class's onViewCreated function**. This is done calling super.onViewCreated from the child class. In your case you're doing your code first in QRCodeFragment and then calling super.onViewCreated which results the **this** of your class to refer to **Base Fragment instance**. To solve this issue, you have to call super.onViewCreated first. It will cause **this** to refer to the QRCodeFragment instance.

Comment: And even you are somehow able to build your app.. Your app will crash as not calling super.onViewCreated first will result the view parameter to be null. As a result you might get NullPointerException

Comment: @DevBhattacharjee Thanks I got all of your points and with the Help of those, I was able to Resolve the Problem :)

Comment: @ DevBhattacharjee I Already Did as You just Answer and I See Someone make a Downvote

Comment: @DevBhattacharjee an Issue Occur as I the camera open it always open in Landscape but the Tutorial I am following will always open portrait mode

Comment: this question is about type mismatch, nothing related to camera... you should post new question instead of commenting in non-relevant topic

Comment: @MichaelButscher you should look at the previous comments and what the person who asked the question said and whom he credited for resolving the issue.

Comment: @UsmanAli You should change and select the actual answer that worked as **selected answer** as it will help others in future.

Comment: imho: Usman had two problems, one was a class mismatch (which was pointed by posted exception) and my answer helped him. and you've found another problem and answered for potential "future" question with misplaced line. our both posts helped, but still mine is answering on posted problem and your got upvote, because it was also helpful and "finally" makes his code work

Answer (score 1):

If your `QRCodeFragment` extends `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` then you should use `IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment`

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment After Adding this the Issue Remains the Same.

Comment: Where do I Use IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment, On Imports?

Comment: @UsmanAli don't use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` it's deprecated, use `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` and `IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment` instead

Comment: But It Does not Shows the androidx.fragment.app.Fragment as I extend the Fragment
It only shows v4 and app fragment

Comment: I need  Liberary in Gragle File?

Comment: You can use "just" `Fragment` because you have some `import` of this class. If you have `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` then you should migrate to AndroidX libraries and use `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`, [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Migration Makes a lot of Error that Become Same as I remove and run thm again

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your imports

you need to change your import from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `android.app.Fragment` or vice versa

Comment: I have Changed this but after that From Where I am Calling Fragment, type Mismatched error goes there

Answer (score 0):

**In onViewCreated** you're first doing your stuff and then calling **super.onViewCreated**.

**this** is referring to the **Base Fragment instance** and as your code goes before the **super** call, it assumes your **Fragment type** is **Fragment** and not **QRCodeFragment**
To solve this

`First call super.onViewCreated in onViewCreated and then do your code part`

**Do this**-

```
override fun onViewCreated(view:View, savedInstanceState:Bundle? ) 
{
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState) 
//your code part
}
```

Comment: I'm the downvoter, sorry for the late answer: As the other answers already suggest the real problem was that the `Fragment` class came from the main API and the one from a compatibility library was expected instead. If the `Fragment` from main API would have been expected then it wouldn't cause this type of error if an object of derived class like `QRCodeFragment` was provided instead because at least at compile time it is always correct to use a derived class object instead of a base class object as parameter. Your suggested reordering of calls could not help to solve the original issue.

Comment: It was not a compatibility issue. You should first look first what the person asked. It was not only with reordering with function calls. The reordering was required as **call** to the **super class methods** were required first.  The ```QRFragment``` class inherited the ```Fragment``` class and ```some methods from Fragment class were overridden```. As a result ```this``` was referring to ```Fragment``` and not```QRFragment``` class which is why ```the type mismatch was shown```. It was resolved when the user did exactly what I said.

Comment: The reordering may solve a possible runtime issue but it is just not possible that the compile time type mismatch is caused by the wrong order.